# Formula for curved capacitance 'plates'

Tags: capacitance

What is the capacitance formula between two (2) evenly curved plates?

Imagine these plate halves curved around on opposite ends of a cylindrical dielectric material. Assume the curvature angle as 'theta' where 0 <= theta <=180 degrees. @theta=180 degrees, they become standard parallel plate capacitors whose formula is well known.

[image]

Comment: You mean like a Leyden Jar? Seem like a homework question to me.

Comment: Curvature angle?!? I think you need to add a diagram that explains the geometry you're talking about.

Comment: What about the capacitance between concentric spheres. Would that help because it is solved and might provide insight.

Comment: @Oldfart ...this is NOT a homework issue but a design problem I'm working on for a customer.

Comment: @Dave ...added picture as requested.

Comment: @Andy, two concentric spheres, cylinders or concentric anything is not what I'm looking for. Please see attached diagram. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't see how theta=180 becomes equivalent to a parallel-plate capacitor. Your diagram doesn't show what theta actually controls.

Comment: Now it makes more sense. My approach would be to use a numerical program approach: integrate using small steps. Also you arrow is pointing to the outside circle which, if your shapes are solid, should be pointing to the inside circle as the outside does not matter.

Comment: If the diagram is at all to scale, the capacitance will be dominated by the flat areas on each side.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, the formula is easy: it's
$$C = Q/V$$
and you find V by solving for the E field with a test charge +Q on one
plate, -Q on the other,
and integrating (line integral)
$$V = \int \overline E \cdot  d\overline L $$
from any convenient point on one electrode, to the other.

The charge isn't equally distributed over the area of the plates,
its location IS on the outer surface, with E inside the outer surface
set to zero.

It gets more complicated because of the dielectric and/or nearby metal
structures, and the geometry is not self-shielding, so technically
you need to know all the surroundings out to infinity to complete the
E-field calculation.

The electrode shapes are boundaries, with boundary conditions that
amount to the E-field component parallel to the surface vanishing at
zero distance from the surface.   As boundaries go, these are not
simple shapes.   The field solution, therefore, is not going to be
simple.

If the problem can be made two-dimensional (i.e. very long device,
with constant cross-section), there are conformal mapping solutions
that can create symmetry and make the on-paper problem tractable.
Otherwise, the use of finite-element modeling would give good results,
but not a general formula.   Practical capacitors have uniform field
in the dielectric, and negligible field outside the dielectric, so
approximate solutions are very simple.   This, however, is not a
practical capacitor in that sense.